# Stripe when processing

Tags: stripe-payments

I have this Stripe error when I try to process a membership on a card.

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
> No such plan: '2'
> Extracted source (around line #12):

```
  def save_with_subscription
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
```

Can someone please help me understand what I'am not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're likely passing 2 as the value for `plan_id`. This is actually a very legacy way of implementing billing. You likely want to instead create the Customer:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, source: stripe_card_token)
```

Then create the related Subscription.

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(
  customer: customer.id, 
  items: [{
    plan: 'plan_123abc' # the plan or price ID from dashboard.stripe.com
  }]
)
```

Note that most of these are legacy. Cards and Sources have been largely replaced by PaymentMethod. Plan has been replaced by Price.

Have a look at this guide for the recommended approach: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#collect-payment

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'll try that.  I'am new to programming and taking computer science as a major this fall!  I appreciate your help.